# Bluetooth Mouse appear and Disappear

Tags: 10.04, mouse, bluetooth

On my Dell Precision M4500 with embedded Bluetooth device I've used for 6 month a Logitech M555b Bluetooth Mouse on Ubuntu 10.04 with no problem.
After the latest update (Automatic Update) of Ubuntu, my mouse stopped pairing with my pc.

I deleted the device from the Bluetooth Preferences device list and clicked again "Set Up New Device" button, but in the device search the mouse appear and disappear, or if I select the mouse from the list and I can click the "Forward" button it gives me an error like that one:

[image: Device Setup Failed]

Some times a popup comes out, and say a thing like:
Grant access to '0000 ... other number loong number'
Device "Logitech Bluetooth Mouse M555b" (00:??:?? other numbers separated with ":")
wants access to the service
'0000... other number loong number similar to the first one...'.

There is also a Bug Report about this issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/774854

Comment: have you tried the solution given there ,comment # 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by pairing my mouse with another PC... after that my mouse paired again smoothly.

Comment: This was the fix for the issue on my system as well thanks. (dell inspirion 14z, UBuntu 11.10)

Answer (score 0):

The Logitech Bluetooth Mouse M555b works out of the box for me on Ubuntu 11.10 with a [Trendnet Bluetooth adaptater](http://www.trendnet.com/products/proddetail.asp?prod=175_TBW-107UB&cat=10). No seting up was required. So you may want to upgrade your operating system to a newer version.